# Software to create repositories of students' software projects

Tags: undergraduate, plagiarism, software, repository

I want to be able to store the software projects my students submit so I can catch plagiarism. Some students copy work from previous years and it would be really helpful if I could find a way to store all projects so I could compare.

My university currently uses moodle but I can't find a way to create a project repository to detect plagiarism. (We do have the JPlag detection system but that only works for projects submitted under one particular group (assignment)).

Any ideas?

Comment: I and my university have used Moss by Stanford (http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/) - I'm not sure of its effectiveness to detect slight modifications, but it seems to be the standard of most university CS programs.

Comment: I've been trying to get registered with MOSS but i haven't received any replies.. Is there a group @Ryan that i could post to? Thank you.

Comment: Really? I was able to register with them a while ago before. Maybe do they have a support email?

Comment: @Ryan I used my official email and it worked, though they've said that moss is open for any email now.

Answer (score 5):

I and my university have used MOSS (Measure of Software Similarity) by Stanford ([theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss)) - I'm not sure of its effectiveness to detect slight modifications, but it seems to be the standard of most university CS programs.

Answer (score 0):

Have been using a Plagiarism plugin integrated on Moodle Server. This plugin integrates with assignment, forum and workshop activities in Moodle to check user-submitted content for plagiarism [provided by UniCheck](https://moodle.org/plugins/plagiarism_unicheck) Course faculty can view the complete plagiarism report, including plagiarism within the class. Plagiarism score/Report can be also shown to students (Optional).

Answer (score -5):

A software program can be coded in multiple ways, which renders plagiarism softwares impossible to detect similar projects/files. Students often change the variables, method names, comments, etc.

In case somebody simply copies a project without a single modification, It can be detected by jPlag. But in case of slight modifications, it is impossible for such softwares to detect plagiarism. Maybe in future AI can prove this whole thing possible.

Comment: My question really is about being able to build a repository for projects and then use that to check for plagiarism. What JPlag offers to the best of my knowledge is detecting plagiarism in one group. I'm looking for something like turnitin for source code where it checks against old work too and stores it.

Comment: You know nothing about how software works. Everything you've said in your answer is wrong: -1